# Unity Oculus Quest 2 low fps

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, quest

I have a problem with my VR game.

I have build a simple scene, and when I start the game, RivaTuner shows 90-80 frames per second, but when I put on the headset, the frame rate is very low, I want to know why it works like that.

I used Oculus Quest 2 with Oculus Link.

Comment: Have you tried building the Game using "Build&Run" or do you run it from within the Unity Editor? The Editor might have a significant performance impact.

Comment: i build project